# How to add parameters to a reverse route in Play2?

Tags: templates, scala, playframework-2.0

My homepage has a GET form for searching:

```
  val searchForm = Form (
      tuple(
        "address" -> nonEmptyText,
        "latitude" -> nonEmptyText,
        "longitude" -> nonEmptyText
      )
    )
```

The search result page itself saves the form parameters in the session. The user then navigates from the results to detail pages on the locations.

On top of the detail page there are breadcrumbs that let the user navigate back to the search results. So in there I need a link with the form parameters appended:

```
<a href="@routes.Application.search()...add something here?...">Search for "@session.get("search_address")"</a>
```

- How do I add the form parameters without manually building and url
  encoding?
- Is there a better way to handle this scenario?

Comment: I've edited to remove "(Scala)" from your title, and added the `scala` tag. You shouldn't be putting things like that in the title, that's exactly what tags are for!

Comment: Do you want to add a paramater to the query string or to the path?

Answer (score 2):

The search action should be defined like this:

```
GET  /search  controllers.Application.search(address: String, latitude: String, longitude: String)
```

And then you call it like this (use `get` only if you can be sure the address will be there):

```
@routes.Application.search(session.get("address").get, ...)
```

Comment: That way I have to duplicate the form validation somehow... but makes sense. I would still like to know if it's possible to add extra params to the reverse route though.

Comment: You don't have to duplicate anything, you can combine parameters and form binding.